# Wrong input arguments for MALLET topic modeling?

Tags: mallet

I tried to run MALLET topic modeling using the following via command line:

```
bin/mallet import-dir --input data\my_text \
             --output my.mallet \
             --remove-stopwords TRUE \
             --keep-sequence TRUE \
             --gram-sizes 1,2 \
             --keep-sequence-bigrams TRUE
```

I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option 10: 2
    at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption$List.process(CommandOption.java:344)
    at cc.mallet.util.CommandOption.process(CommandOption.java:146)
    at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:122)
```

It appears MALLET recognized "2" after the comma as the 10th argument. Can anyone let me know whether my input is wrong and how to correct this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quote the argument to the `--gram-sizes` option

```
--gram-sizes "1,2" \
```

and it will work.